# SDL Player do something for 3 seconds then stop

Tags: sdl, c, sdl2

I'll make my player respawn after 1 of his lives is taken, but I want him to be invincible for 2 or 3 seconds and not instadie again because he will be in the way of enemy bullets.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BULLETS; i++) if (enemyB[i]) {
    if(globalTime % 2 == 0)
        enemyB[i]->y -= enemyB[i]->dx;
    if (player->alive && (enemyB[i]->x > player->x && enemyB[i]->x < player->x + 97 && enemyB[i]->y == player->y-15))
    {
        if (player->invincible == false) {
            player->life -= 25;
            player->hbSprite++;
        }
        if (player->life <= 0) {
            player->invincible = true;
            player->lives--;
            player->life = 100;
            player->lifeSprite++;
            player->hbSprite = 0;
            if (player->lives <= 0) {
                player->alive = 0;
                player->hbSprite = 4;
                player->lifeSprite = 3;
            }
        }
        removenemyB(i);
    }
}
```

When I set player->invicible = true he's not taking dmg , but I need him to do that only for 2 or 3 seconds , help pls.

Comment: Well you need to create some sort of timer (at least manually keep track of how much time has elapsed since you set `invincible` to `true`) - What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: Nothing really , I don't really understood the sdl_ticks(); function .. I think I can use it..maybe?

Comment: That would be one option (although probably not the best one). You could also try using [`SDL_AddTimer`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryTimer%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruc%29).

Comment: By the way a quick google search showed [this tutorial](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson12/index.php) which seems to do the same thing you need (also using `SDL_GetTicks()`, so maybe I was wrong and it is a good solution)

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are working with SDL2, [`SDL_GetTicks()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks) is the most straightforward solution. [`SDL_AddTimer`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryTimer%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruc%29) is also an option, but you would have to deal with a bit of multi-threading, unnecessary repeated executions, and callback functions.

I see that you have a `globalTime` variable, which I am inclined to incorporate as part of my answer, but I don't have enough context with the code you've provided to be sure how that variable is updated.

That being said, replace setting invincibility with *the game time that the player will no longer be invincible*:

```
// ...
if (player->life <= 0) {
    player->endInvincibleTime = SDL_GetTicks() + 3000; // 3 seconds
// ...

// endInvincibleTime is Uint32 type
```

This amounts to setting a marker at some fixed point in the future. Game time will eventually pass it, permanently.

Then, instead of checking for invincibility, just check if game time has passed `endInvincibleTime`:

```
// ...
if (player->endInvincibleTime < SDL_GetTicks()) {
    player->life -= 25;
    player->hbSprite++;
}
// ...
```

`SDL_GetTicks` returns an unsigned 32 bit integer, meaning that from the moment `SDL_Init` is called its timer starts counting milliseconds and it is able to count up to 49 *days* worth of milliseconds.

---

Note that I am suggesting here that you use `SDL_GetTicks` as your game duration/timing system directly, but that is only for the sake of example. There are other ways of tracking time. For example using different timing libraries , or  in STL. They more-or-less amount to better precision and/or more reliable response time. [Here's some more reading on C timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer) *Always be wary of integer overflow/wrap-around.* Especially when using unsigned integers.

Comment: A better name for `endInvincibleTime` might be `respawnTime` as that is what the player is doing.

Comment: This should work. It's good to inform people of the existence of other methods but if the asking user is already using the SDL library SDL_GetTicks is the recommended method, and millisecond precision is enough for what he is doing.